# Editing html input element from javascript bugs out

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input field in html:

```
<input id="title" type="text" class="" />
```

A button will allow the user to randomize the value of the input field by calling a js function.

```
var title = document.getElementById("title");
title.removeAttribute("value");
title.setAttribute("value",random_name);
```

If the user wants to change the value auto-asigned by my function (aka random_name), he can simply type something else in the input field.

All works fine until now, however if the user changes his mind and clicks the randomize button again, the function is called and "value" attribute is modified, but the user still sees the last thing he typed and not the new random value.

Is there a way to fix this or maybe a workaround?

Comment: Instead of `title.removeAttribute()` and `title.setAttribute()` just assign to `title.value` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `title.value = random_name`

You can set an input's value by `element.value = "desired_value"`. If you use that, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/f4gVR/2/

```
<input id="title" type="text" class="" />
<input type="button" class="" onclick="randomValue()" value="Random" />

function randomValue() {
  var title = document.getElementById("title");
  title.value = Math.random(); // assign random_name to title.value here
}
```

if it's your `random_name` bugging out, you should post the code. Try this first. Just replace `Math.random()` with `random_name`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `title.value = random_name;` instead of `title.setAttribute("value",random_name);`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dhKa/